# Security Configuration with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

This is my SecurityConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) 
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/Auth/**", "/").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
}
```

This is my basic controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Auth/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    private final AuthService authService;
    @PostMapping("RegisterWithUserNameAndPassword")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerWithUserNameAndPassword(@RequestBody RegisterRequest authRequest){
        try{
            return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.register(authRequest));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("Hello")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello Auth controller");
    }
}
```

When I'm using postman in order to reach "Auth/Hello", everything looks good no errors and the correct String.
When i'm trying to use the browser I'm getting the correct String response but in addition there is also an error:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
```

In Addition those are the debug logs:

```
2023-08-13T16:24:50.955+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /Auth/Hello
2023-08-13T16:24:50.962+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-13T16:24:50.969+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /Auth/Hello
2023-08-13T16:24:50.985+03:00  WARN 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] c.m.security.config.JwtAuthFilter        : No valid jwt token in Authorization
2023-08-13T16:24:51.002+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /favicon.ico
2023-08-13T16:24:51.002+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-13T16:24:51.005+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2023-08-13T16:24:51.008+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-08-13T16:24:51.010+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-13T16:24:51.010+03:00 DEBUG 55724 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

The debug logs after removing the filter again:

```
2023-08-13T23:19:30.050+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /Auth/Hello
2023-08-13T23:19:30.057+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-13T23:19:30.064+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /Auth/Hello
2023-08-13T23:19:30.097+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /favicon.ico
2023-08-13T23:19:30.097+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-13T23:19:30.101+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2023-08-13T23:19:30.103+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-08-13T23:19:30.105+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-13T23:19:30.106+03:00 DEBUG 94616 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Is there any way to fix this error?
Thank you

Comment: Is there any specific reason you have not enabled DEBUG logs and just read what the problem is?

Comment: Added the debug logs to the question

Comment: if you read you logs it is super clear what is going on, you are first trying to access `GET /Auth/Hello` and you get `No valid jwt token in Authorization` in some sort of strange custom JWT-solution. Since you are throwing some sort of strange custom exception spring security redirects you to `GET /error` which is standard spring boot error handling https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling

Comment: Tbh. you have decided to write some strange custom security solution which is bad practice. Writing some strange custom JWTAuthFilter is wrong, using JWTs as sessions is also wrong, what ever blogpost you are following is has no idea what security is, and i suggest you google why you should not use JWTs as sessions because it is extremely dangerous. Then i suggest you learn how error handling in spring boot works, and how spring security works and implement some of the standard things in spring security from the documentation instead of googling bad blogs/tutorials from bad developers.

Comment: downvoted because of bad research and not making an effort to read the spring security docs and just following a bad tutorial that didnt work and then asked here for the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If you'd actually read the full log you would see that this is a warning though, so there is no actually an error being thrown like you are suggesting...

Comment: Added the logs after removing the unused filter again, same thing just without the warning
if you have a better insight I'd like to hear it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254900/discussion-between-itamarled-and-toerktumlare).

Comment: Read what i wrote, and read the link i posted. Then whitelist `/error` endpoint. Enable TRACE logs, and fix your broken request